# C# - How do i add a Hashtable to a Listview?

Tags: c#

C# - How do i add a Hashtable to a Listview?
I have a function that returns a Hashtable and I want to be able to add the contents of the Hashtable to a Listview.

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application? WPF? Silverlight?

Answer (score 1):

Very generic due to lack of info, but something along these lines:

```
foreach (var item in hashtable.Values)
{
    listView.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(item.ToString()));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try is out when I get home.

Comment: I tried this and the listview was full of "System.Collections.Hashtable"

Answer (score 0):

You can provide `ListView's` `DisplayMember` as `Key` of `Hashtable` and `ValueMember` as Value of `HashTable` or vice-versa which ever way you want.